# How i can correctly append div in pagination table

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, angularjs

i have that div. It's ok!

```
<div class="product"><div class="product-list-td col-xs-12 col-sm-12" ng-repeat="products in showProduct">
                    <div class="numeric-prod col-xs-12 col-sm-2">
                        {{$index+1}}
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-2">
                        {{ products.name }}
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-2">
                        {{ products.article }}
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-2">
                        {{ products.description }}
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-2">
                        {{ products.cost }}
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-2"">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning delete-product col-xs-12 col-sm-12" data-ng-click="deleteProduct( products.id )">Delete</button>
                    </div>
                </div></div>
```

i'm try add that div after ng-repeat function. He work. (that code)

```
$scope.productClick = function (event) {
        if ($scope.testId != event)
        {
            $scope.testId = event;
            if ($scope.testId != undefined)
            {
                $scope.productTableName = $filter('filter')($scope.ShopTable, {id: $scope.testId}, true);
                $scope.showProduct = $filter('filter')($scope.ProductTable, {shop_id: $scope.testId}, true);
                $('.product').appendTo('#'+event);
                $('.tr-table .product').css({'display' : 'block'});
                if ($scope.showProduct[0]== undefined)
                {
                    $scope.ProductsShopName = 'No Products';
                }
                else
                {
                    $scope.ProductsShopName = $scope.productTableName[0].name+' product list';
                }
            }
        } else {
            $scope.testId = 0 ;
            $('.tr-table .product').css({'display' : 'none'});
            $('.product').appendTo('.container');
        }
    }
```

Why do I ask - after moving to a new page (dir pagination angularjs), the div added to me in the .tr-table Automatically deleted.
You can see how it happens here http://point.salesdep.by/

Click the button "product" (once), then go to the next page of the table. And click button "product" again. ("not work") because div '.product' removed from the first page. Help please guys!

Comment: clone() does not work, only if you clone twice

Comment: The problem seems to be that the `.product` element is moved and when you change the page there will be no `.product` element on the page to append to the `.container`. Try this: `$($('.product').clone().wrap('<div>').parent().html()).appendTo('.container');`

Comment: You are not doing things the angular way. But you can still reset your div when you change page: check if one of your buttons has been clicked and, if so, reset its state.

Comment: Titus. After adding I tried to clone in .container. It works but it's wrong.  After cloning adds without data. You have to click twice.

Comment: Groben, how i can reset him? After downloading page, save it to the object?

Comment: Not work. $scope.productHtml = $('.product-data-obj').html(); look at now! http://point.salesdep.by/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be easier to do it the angular way. Update you parent div (the `ng-repeat shops`) and add your div with a boolean to display it or not:

```
<div class="row dragger">....</div>
<div class="product" data-ng-show="shop.showList">
    <div class="product-list-td col-xs-12 col-sm-12" ng-repeat="products in shop.showProduct">
        <div class="numeric-prod col-xs-12 col-sm-2">
            {{$index+1}}
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-2">
            {{ products.name }}
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-2">
            {{ products.article }}
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-2">
            {{ products.description }}
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-2">
            {{ products.cost }}
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-2"">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning delete-product col-xs-12 col-sm-12" data-ng-click="deleteProduct( products.id )">Delete</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And update your controller accordingly (my response probably doesn't work, it's just to give you the main idea):

```
$scope.productClick = function (shop) {
    //if you want to hide all other div, you can loop here over shops to
    //set all showList at false
    shop.showList = !shop.showList;
    if(true === shop.showList){
        //this part is probably false
        //you need to fetch the data here so you can display it
        $scope.testId = shop.id;
        $scope.productTableName = $filter('filter')($scope.ShopTable, {id: $scope.testId}, true);
        shop.showProduct = $filter('filter')($scope.ProductTable, {shop_id: $scope.testId}, true);

        if (shop.showProduct[0]== undefined)
            {
                $scope.ProductsShopName = 'No Products';
            }
            else
            {
                $scope.ProductsShopName = $scope.productTableName[0].name+' product list';
            }
        }
    }
}
```